# Image Is Ignoring Div Container

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img>
    <div>
    <table>...</table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#img { 
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
}
```

Both divs are the same size as the table.
I want the image to float top right of the table.
This results that the img is at the right side of the screen and not in the div.

Comment: do you mean `absolute`? Also, set your div to `position:relative;`

Comment: What happens, what do you want to happen? And yes you probably mean absolute.

Comment: Also, `#img {` will position any element with id = 'img', and not an img element; but looking at your description of the issue, I think you already had that good, and just posted it wrong into StackOverflow.

Comment: You edited your question. But is the problem still there? It can confuse those trying to help you.

Comment: And in case you're wondering, the `position:relative;` in the div is necessary, because it tells the browser that subsequent child elements with absolute positioning must be positioned relative to this parent. If you don't add it, its positioning relative to the `<html>` tag.

Comment: I edited absolut so people can see what happened and what you are up to. If you just fix the question the answers may be invalid altogether.

Comment: `position:relative` was what I was missing. "absolute" was my error because I didn't copy my code

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `position:relative;` to the containing div. Also, I would advise against using tables unless you will be displaying tabular data, they should not be used for layout.

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.container img {
  position:absolute; /* absolute misspelled in your example */
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
    <div>
    <table></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 'position:relative;' that was what I was missing thanks a lot.

Comment: As @BenHillier explains above, `position:relative;` is necessary because `position:absolute;` removes the element from the document flow. By adding relative positioning to the parent element, the absolute position of the image becomes relative to it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

`img` ignore `width` set to their `parent`. Apply `width` to `img` **itself** instead.

Also, you misspelled "absolute".